# I want to implement SharePoint, but I want to design it my way

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, master-pages

I am aware of a program called "SharePoint Designer 20xx), and I would like to know if any of you have modified the default master page to make it.. less confusing and more simplistic. Can this be however I want it or is there limitations?

I also found this:
http://www.expertsharepointconsulting.com/images/Blue%20Large.PNG

I would like to implement a design similar to this! If I were to download a "Free sharepoint master page", would this design only work for the main page of SharePoint? as in if I were to go from the newly added masterpage, to a page called "reports", would it be completely different? If so how can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create customized masterpages whichever way you want. Usually you don't touch the default ones, specially because you can break some system pages with that. Just create new ones from them or from the minimum.master one.

As an example of a Sharepoint Website using a very customized master page I can point you to a publishing website project I was involved for a Portuguese company: http://www.ana.pt/en-US/Pages/Homepage.aspx

It's all Sharepoint 2010...and it is fully customized

You can of course use the same template for all pages, just have to set it on the root site and say that all sub sites inherit from it.

To achieve the level of design changes you see on that web site you have to build new master pages, page layouts, use JS, CSS and user controls (the website uses little to no web parts).

we don't use Sharepoint designer because that would mean the files becoming unghosted, which can be pain sometimes, and sharepoint designer is not a very good tool.

The way we do it is by implementing everything on visual studio and deploying it via WSP packages. This way everything stays ghosted on the file system. You can check an example here:
http://mihirsharepoint.wordpress.com/2012/11/23/creating-custom-master-page-in-visual-studio-and-deploy-it-to-the-sharepoint-site/

Comment: it is a very nice site.

Comment: im just gathering as much information as a can for creating a new layout and also installing excel services to work on sharepoint. Thanks for the help!!